# How to show in diff that a file was just deleted

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have a GIT repository with many very large files that I've deleted in my recent change. Using `git-diff` generates this giant `diff` file that is difficult to work with. The reason the file is giant is because it lists the contents of the files that were deleted.

Is there any way to create a diff version that will just list that a file was deleted? I've tried `--irreversible-delete` but it doesn't look like our GIT 1.7.3.2 supports it. Using `--diff-filter` won't work either.
Does diff format actually have an option to list file as deleted without all the old contents?

Comment: git status will do that for you- if that is all you wanted?

Comment: No, that's not what I want, unfortunately. I want a diff with no old file contents, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upgrade to a version of Git at least 1.7.6, where the option was added.

Note that you can still use the older version of Git as well; you just need to use the newer one to produce the diffs.

Comment: It works, thank you. Really need to push our IT to get GIT upgraded.